# Using string as literal expression in function argument in Python

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a function that can take various kinds of parameter values, but I don't want to (as a constraint) pass arguments explicitly. Instead, I want to pass them as a string.:

```
def func(param)
   return param+param

a = 'param=4'
func(<do something to a>(a))

>>8
```

Is this possible in python?

I want to use this idea in Django to create Query filters based on GET parameters in a dictionary and then just chain them using their keys.

```
lookup_dic = {'user': 'author=user',
              'draft': 'Q(publish_date_lte=timezone.now())|
                        Q(publish_date_isnull=True)'}
```

Based on whether the user and draft keywords are passed in the `GET` parameters, this would be read out like:

```
queryset.objects.filter(author=user).filter(Q(publish_date_lte=timezone.now())|
                                           Q(publish_date_isnull=True))
```

I understand that I can do this by replacing the `author=user` by `Q(author__name=user)`, but I wanted to know if this string comprehension feature is implemented in python in general?

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval`

```
def func(param=0):
    return param+param

a = 'param=4'
eval('func(' + a +')')
```

Comment: I was looking for something of the tune of `func(eval(a))` (Which of course, does not work).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
def func(param):
    return param + param


a = 'param=4'
parameter, value = a.split("=")
print(func(**{parameter: int(value)}))
# >> 8
```